# Euclidean construction of one degree angle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

We can construct 15 degrees by bisecting 60 degrees twice.
We can construct 37 degrees by constructing a right angled triangle with sides 3 and 4 since tan 37 is 3÷4
We can also similarly construct 53 degrees
When we have constructed 37 and 53 we can construct 53 -37 = 16 degrees 
Since we have constructed 15 and 16 we can construct 16-15 =1 degree
But if we can construct 1 degree we can construct 20 degrees
This means we can trisect 60 degrees which is supposed to be impossible by euclidean means 
What is the mistake in this procedure?

Comment: Well, for example, $\arctan(3/4) \neq 37^\circ$...

Comment: If you are trying to do abstract geometric constructions, approximations aren't useful.  $\tan (37^{\circ})\approx .753554$, it's not even that good an approximation to $.75$

Comment: Thanks did not know that tan37 is not exactly 3/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is that $\tan(37^\circ) \approx 0.7535540501 \neq 0.75 \approx \tan(36.87^\circ)$.

As an aside, it is not *always* necessarily impossible to trisect an angle - in a few special cases, there are some angles that can be trisected. For example, you can construct a $45^\circ$ angle by bisecting a right angle, and you can also construct a $15^\circ = \tfrac{1}{3}\cdot 45^\circ$ angle by bisecting a $30^\circ$ angle. So naturally, this means that a $45^\circ$ angle can be trisected.

The angle trisection constructability result you are referring to says rather that it is not possible to trisect *all* angles, in general. In particular, for angles of an integral amount of degrees (i.e. $1^\circ, 2^\circ, 3^\circ$, ...) it is possible to construct only the angles which are integer multiples of $3^\circ$ (i.e. $3^\circ, 6^\circ, 9^\circ$, ...).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1693856/928654 1

Constructing an angle with an integer number of degrees not divisible by 3
 implies (and is equivalent to) the ability to construct a 1∘
 angle, from which one can construct a regular 9
-gon, and that cannot be done with ruler and compass.